# Finding Number of Days Since a User Changed Their Password

Tags: python, password, users

I have searched and searched, but I'm struggling to find anything close to this. This is the task I'm trying to accomplish using Python within Ubuntu:
find and print the following information:

- The number of days since the password was last changed (prompt for username)
- I need to present this number in date format

I can list the date changed as it appears in /etc/shadow, but i need it in date format.

Comment: Is the question about how to find the information or is it about how to write the code to present the information with your Python code? The latter would be off-topic here I guess. and better placed at stackoverflow.com. Please make that more clear.

Comment: It is using Python to find this in Ubuntu. I tried here first as it pertains to Ubuntu.

Comment: So what are you having trouble with? Finding users with no password? Password age?

Comment: I have found a way to list all users but i'm not sure how to find the users with no password currently. (Also have no idea how to display the # of days since password was changed after a username is inputted)

Comment: There is a python module for this kind of thing: [spwd — The shadow password database](https://docs.python.org/2/library/spwd.html#module-spwd)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `chage` utility (part of the `passwd` package):

```
chage -l $user
```

`chage` requires root privileges but any user can use `chage -l` for itself.

Comment: Nice, but works only with local users :(

Comment: @pLumo uh? what do you mean by "local" here?

Comment: I mean e.g. LDAP users, and I think here it would be interesting.

Comment: Erm, all your findings are local. You are searching in a local directory /etc on a local file shadow o_O.. It will show you the local rights on this machine for the user (if it is connected to LDAP or not does not matter).

Comment: I don't get you, I am connected with ldap and it does not work. It says `chage: user xxxx does not exist in /etc/passwd`. On the same machine I have a local user, and it works perfectly for that one.

Comment: @pLumo Feel free to ask another question mentioning LDAP